# Using grunt watch with livereload

Tags: livereload, grunt-contrib-watch

I am trying to use the grunt watch plugin to compile coffeescript and sass. I want to use livereload in addition so that I can instantly see the results. This is my grunt configuration - but it does not actually reload the loaded page when I make a modification. Please help me fix this.

```
watch:
      sass:
        files: ['client/**/*.scss']
        tasks: ['sass:all']
        options:
          spawn: false
          livereload: true
      coffee:
        files: ['client/**/*.coffee', 'server/**/*.coffee', 'test/**/*.coffee']
        tasks: ['coffee:all']
        options:
          spawn: false
          livereload: true
```

Comment: Actually, it's possible but you can't use grunt-contrib-connect. Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18186455/grunt-js-fire-livereload-as-soon-a-files-are-modified-before-task-completes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm currently experiencing the same issue.  `spawn` has a default value of `true` - If you leave it like that it will likely work.

Unfortunately, in my scenario, I require that `spawn=false` - I'll let you know if I find a fix.

Edit - I did some reading, and it doesn't look like it's possible.  If `spawn=false` the watch task has to exit while it executes the task list for a watch target - After it finishes, watch restarts, but it won't see any files created/updated whilst it wasn't running.

In your situation I'd recommend removing the `spawn: false` line so that it uses the default value for spawn (which is `true`).